# Add node to xml file with properties through java

Tags: java, xml

I am new to XML parsing in Java
I have an XML file

```
<root>
    <project name="A">
        <Sub name="abc">
            <first property1="ab" property2="cd" property3="ed"/>
            <second property1="aa" property2="dd" property3="ke"/>
        </Sub>
    </project>
</root>
```

I need to add another node as second with different property values
(i.e.,)

```
<root>
    <project name="A">
        <Sub name="abc">
            <first property1="ab" property2="cd" property3="ed"/>
            <second property1="aa" property2="dd" property3="ke"/>
            <second property1="oa" property2="ld" property3="je"/>
        </Sub>
    </project>
</root>
```

Can anyone tell me how to go ahead and implement in java?

Comment: We don't write code from scratch. Show us what you've attempted and we'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using jdom. Include [jdom jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom/2.0.2) in your classpath.

```
            Document document = (Document) new SAXBuilder().build(new File("E:/input.xml"));
            Element sub = document.getRootElement().getChild("project").getChild("Sub");            
            Element second = new Element("second");
            second.setAttribute("property1", "aa");
            second.setAttribute("property2", "dd");

            sub.addContent(second);

            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
            xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat().setOmitDeclaration(true));         
            xmlOutput.output(document, System.out);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this sequence :

1. Deserialize this data into a java object [XML to Java Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731322/xml-parsing-and-deserialization)
2. Edit it by adding whatever and dump the xml into the file